# Como recuperar a imagem da pasta Storage usando INTERVENTION IMAGE Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, image, laravel-5.2

Esta solução funciona na pasta Public mais ao trocar para pasta Storage não consigo pegar a imagem e exibir na view alguém pode me ajudar?

**Controller**

```
  public function profile(){
    return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()) );
}

public function update_avatar(Request $request){

    if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( storage_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename ) );

        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->avatar = $filename;
        $user->save();
    }
    return  view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()) );
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('profile',
'UserController@profile');

Route::post('profile',
'UserController@update_avatar');
```

**View**
Essa era a chamada que eu fazia para retorna a imagem quando estava na pasta public agora que esta na pasta Storage não funciona, alguém sabe como posso pegar a image da pasta storage e exibir na view?

```
<img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}">
```

**Repository GitLab**
https://gitlab.com/ronnyere/Laravel.git

Comment: Você fez todo procedimento e criou o [link para a pasta igual está na documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk)?

Answer (score 1):

Você vai precisar criar uma rota e uma ação de controlador específica para carregar as imagens, pois a pasta storage não é, ou não deve, ser acessada diretamente pelas chamadas do navegador.

Por exemplo:

Rota

```
Route::get('/user/picture', 'UserController@getPicture');
```

Controlador

```
public function getPicture() {
    return \Image::make(file_get_contents('file://'.storage_path('app/fotos/' . Auth::user()->id . 'png')))->response();
}
```

Visão

```
<img src="/user/picture">
```

**Note** que você precisa adaptar nomes de variáveis e o nome do arquivo para o seu contexto